# Java IF Statement (Algorithm efficiency improvement)

Tags: java, performance

I used method a that counts the amount of possible choices for getting like number 10 with numbers that are from **0 to 6.** Problem is that **it just takes too much time** when **x is like 50** or something. I  just need some tips what I should do to make this faster.

Code

```
public static int count(int x) {
    if (x < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (x == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        result += count(x - i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Generally if your program works without error, but you want to make it work *better*, your question is more appropriate on the [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) exchange than here.

Comment: Have you tried to find a closed form formula instead of using recursion? i.e. have you tried to expressed count(n) as a function of n instead of a function of count(n-1), ..., count(n-6)? This is a math problem.

Comment: I don't understand what it is supposed to do.

Comment: [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) could help, though there is probably a better approach in general.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variation on Fibonacci except it is the sum of the last six values instead.

You can use a plain loop which will be faster than memorisation (the first time)

```
public static long count(int x) {
    long a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, e=0, f=1;
    while(x-- > 0) {
       long sum = a + b + c + d + e + f;
       a = b; b = c; c = d; d = e; e = f;
       f = sum;
    }
    return f;
}
```

If you call this repeatedly you may as well store all the values in the `int` range which is likely to be less than 30 the first time and retrieve these values after that.

Comment: You need to return something.

Comment: Apparently it's [hexanacci, or oeis A001592](https://oeis.org/A001592) - who knew.